# How to fix nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 6 [9: Bad file descriptor] when working with Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, multiprocessing

First of all apologies for this noob question but I am just starting to play around with Python.

When I run the code below I always get an error message:

> 2019-01-13 13:07:28.461945+0100 Python[2246:76361] nw_path_close_fd
>   Failed to close guarded necp fd 6 [9: Bad file descriptor]

Here is the whole output: 
[image]

If I comment the sentence: `client = Client("<apikey>", "<apisecret>") or t = mp.Process(target=hello, args=(i,))` I don't get this error anymore. I don't understand why that is because those processes are not really linked to each other.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
from binance.client import Client

base_currency = "BNB"
client = Client("<apikey>", "<apisecret>")


def runProcess():
    print("runprocess")
    processes = [ ]
    for i in range(2):
        print("mp")
        t = mp.Process(target=hello, args=(i,))
        processes.append(t)
        t.start()

def hello(n):
    print("call hello")
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
    print("[{0}] Hello!".format(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("main")
    runProcess()
```

I expect the output without errors

Comment: Just a wild guess (I don't know/have binance): It is (trying to) do something to stdin/stdout, most probably closing them which conflicts with inheriting them to the hello processes.

Comment: It's not the python-binance library; it does not mess with stdin/stdout.I can run the same code you have above with no errors (on macOS). What OS are you using?

Comment: I am on macOS Mojave version 10.14.2

Comment: tried to change it under the __name__ == '__main__' but without luck

Comment: Update: When building it in Sublime Text I dont have an issue. I only have it with Xcode

Comment: Interesting. I've never tried executing python scripts from Xcode at all, so can't comment on that. macOS comes with a relatively old version of Python generally, so I would recommend installing the latest Python 3.7 (or 2.x if you have a specific reason to need that) instead of using the built-in interpreter.

Comment: I was already working with 3.7 thanks

Comment: From the comments this looks like a platform speciific problem. You should perhaps add the respective tags (macos, xcode) so that people knowing the platform can find the question.

Comment: @ArneVanham, were you able to solved/understand the issue? I'm also having this. Thank you